# Android: Use postInvalidate() or a direct call to onDraw?

Tags: java, android, animation, android-canvas, ondraw

From what I understand, direct calls can be made to the `onDraw` method, and `postInvalidate()` simply calls the `onDraw` method from a separate thread. If I understand correctly (and correct me if I'm wrong), both seem to produce the same result. Is there a difference between `postInvalidate()` and a direct call to `onDraw`? Is one a better practice than the other?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.  Calling postInvalidate sets up the canvas to the screen and passes it to the onDraw function, as well as various other pieces of logic.  Calling onDraw directly only makes sense if you want to draw a view to somewhere other than the screen.

In addition, postInvalidate will cause it to redraw *after control returns to the looper* and combines multiple reasons to redraw into a single redraw.  It will not try to draw immediately.  Calling onDraw would cause it to draw immediately, which may cause significant performance issues.  It will not batch drawing requests, causing it to redraw multiple times.

There's others, but the end result is that unless you're trying to draw to a non-standard canvas, don't call onDraw directly-  call invalidate or postInvalidate.